# register_buffer a dict object in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, state-dict

I thought this was a simple question but I couldn't find an answer.

I want a member variable of a pytorch module to be saved/loaded with model state_dict. I can do that in **init** with the following line.

```
        self.register_buffer('loss_weight', torch.tensor(loss_weight))
```

But what if loss_weight is a dict object? Is it allowed? If so, how can I convert it to a tensor?

When tried, I got an error "Could not infer dtype of dict."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.register_buffer), the `name` argument must be a string, and the `tensor` argument must be a pytorch tensor.

If you have a dict of buffers, you could consider using a dedicated `nn.Module` for that purpose. Something like this:

```py
class BufferDict(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dict):
        super().__init__()
        for k,v in input_dict.items():
            self.register_buffer(k, v)
            
input_dict = {'a' : torch.randn(4), 'b' : torch.randn(5)}

bd = BufferDict(input_dict)
bd.state_dict()
> OrderedDict([('a', tensor([ 0.1908,  1.6965, -0.3710,  0.4551])),
               ('b', tensor([-0.6943, -0.0534,  0.1779,  1.3607, -0.2236]))])
```

Comment: The registered value must be a tensor. You cannot put non-tensor objects into `register_buffer`. With the code I provided, you can reconstruct the dict from the module's `state_dict`

Comment: I ended up using array and enum instead of dict so that I didn't have to reconstruct the dict at loading.